# Getting last column in a particular row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a function that returns the number of columns in a specific row

```
    function lastcolinrow(row)
{
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wtZDazZ5qxeuV65k7Cr-704Sbx-in6qDx-3JmjthTrM");
  var sheet = tss.getSheetByName("Tickets2");
  var data = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,20).getValues().filter(String);
  Logger.log(data);
  for(var i = 0 ; i<=20 ; i++){
    
    if (data[0][i] == ''){
      return i +1 ;
    }
  }
}
```

Im getting a null result

Comment: It looks like you have an error in your filter. Can you verify this:`var data = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,20).getValues().filter(String);` where is "String"?

Answer (score 1):

For any range, you can get the number of rows using:

`var rows = data.length`

To get the number of columns, try:

`var cols = data[0].length`

This gets the first row in range `data`, then checks it's length.